# Dependencies problem when installing ansible in ubuntu 18.04

Tags: python, dependencies, ansible

I try to reinstall ansible in my ubuntu18.04 laptop.

I've got this dependencies problem :

```
$ LANG=C sudo apt-get install ansible
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 ansible : Depends: python-httplib2 but it is not going to be installed
           Recommends: python-winrm (>= 0.1.1) but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

So when I try this packet :

```
$ LANG=C sudo apt-get install python-httplib2
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 python-httplib2 : Depends: python:any (< 2.8)
                   Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.5-5~)
                   Depends: ca-certificates but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Of course, python (2.7 & 3.6)  and ca-certificates are well installed and functional.

When I try to install this packet via synaptic, Synaptic propose me to remove almost all the ubuntu packets :/

If I try to install manually the .deb from https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/libs/python-httplib2

I've got this :

```
$  LANG=C sudo dpkg -i Téléchargements/python-httplib2_0.9.2+dfsg-1_all.deb 
Selecting previously unselected package python-httplib2.
(Reading database ... 236487 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../python-httplib2_0.9.2+dfsg-1_all.deb ...
Unpacking python-httplib2 (0.9.2+dfsg-1) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python-httplib2:
 libssl1.1:amd64 (1.1.1-1ubuntu2.1~18.04.5) breaks python-httplib2 (<= 0.9.2+dfsg-1) and is installed.
  Version of python-httplib2 to be configured is 0.9.2+dfsg-1.

dpkg: error processing package python-httplib2 (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 python-httplib2
```

this is certainly why, by removing libssl1.1:amd64 , synaptic want to remove all ubuntu...

I verify, all my packets are OK
 -  sudo apt install -f 
 -  sudo apt --fix-broken install
 -  sudo apt install --reinstall libssl1.1 python-httplib2
 - ... 
All the magic commands i usualy try to resolv this situation.

I find in /var/log/apt/* that 9 month a go, ansible was removed (with this famous python-httplib2 )  (I usualy don't use ansible from my laptop...):

```
Start-Date: 2019-09-02  16:40:54
Commandline: apt install libio-socket-ssl-perl libnet-ssleay-perl libpython3.6 libpython3.6-dev libpython3.6-minimal libpython3.6-stdlib libssl-dev libssl1.1 openssl python-cryptography python3-cryptography python3.6 python3.6-dev python3.6-minimal
Requested-By: cesnault (1000)
Upgrade: libpython3.6-minimal:amd64 (3.6.5-3, 3.6.8-1~18.04.1), libnet-ssleay-perl:amd64 (1.84-1build1, 1.84-1ubuntu0.2), openssl:amd64 (1.1.0g-2ubuntu4.3, 1.1.1-1ubuntu2.1~18.04.4), libpython3.6-dev:amd64 (3.6.5-3, 3.6.8-1~18.04.1), libpython3.6-stdlib:amd64 (3.6.5-3, 3.6.8-1~18.04.1), libpython3.6:amd64 (3.6.5-3, 3.6.8-1~18.04.1), python3.6:amd64 (3.6.5-3, 3.6.8-1~18.04.1), libio-socket-ssl-perl:amd64 (2.056-1, 2.060-3~ubuntu18.04.1), python3.6-minimal:amd64 (3.6.5-3, 3.6.8-1~18.04.1), python-cryptography:amd64 (2.1.4-1ubuntu1.2, 2.1.4-1ubuntu1.3), python3-cryptography:amd64 (2.1.4-1ubuntu1.2, 2.1.4-1ubuntu1.3), libssl-dev:amd64 (1.1.0g-2ubuntu4.3, 1.1.1-1ubuntu2.1~18.04.4), libssl1.1:amd64 (1.1.0g-2ubuntu4.3, 1.1.1-1ubuntu2.1~18.04.4), python3.6-dev:amd64 (3.6.5-3, 3.6.8-1~18.04.1)
Remove: ansible:amd64 (2.5.1+dfsg-1ubuntu0.1), python-httplib2:amd64 (0.9.2+dfsg-1)
End-Date: 2019-09-02  16:42:37
```

but I can't figure out why I install this lib for ?

Any idea will be welcome please

Thank you.

Cédric

Comment: `ca-certificates` is a rather essential package. It ought to be installed on your system. The current version for Ubuntu 18.04 is 20180409. It appears the whole installation depends on that package. Try `apt policy ca-certificates`.

Comment: Hello and welcome to AskUbuntu: Please use `LANG=C` befor every command. This way also non french speaking people will be able to provide an answer

Comment: @SimonSudler  Thank-you, i update english codes review.

Comment: @Jos ca-certificates is fully functional and good version 20180409

Comment: I have the same problem. It's infuriating.

Comment: No solution found. I must use a docker image with ansible.
Wait to see if dist-upgrade to 20.04 solve this issue.